# Setting variable equal to count of a field in database table

Tags: php, mysql

For the query below, I would like to set a variable called `$totalcount` equal to the count of all `loginid`s in table called `login`.  How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStrcount = "SELECT loginid FROM login";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sqlQueryStr = "SELECT loginid FROM login";
$sqlQuery = mysql_query($sqlQueryStr);

$totalCount = mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery);
```

If you only need to count your records in login use this instead
for performance reasons.

```
$sqlQueryStr = "SELECT COUNT(loginid) as totalCount FROM login";
$sqlQuery = mysql_query($sqlQueryStr);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery);
$totalCount = $row['totalCount'];
```